# React Native getting name of TextInput in OnChange

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to make a general onChange handler for multiple TextInput s.
However when I access the event, the best I can get is event.nativeEvent which has 3 keys.

eventCount, target, and text

target is only a number. I realize from the docs that 'name' is not a prop of TextInput. Is there a way to pass in a prop to the TextInput so I can get it later in onChange and then set the state based on that?

I have 2 TextInputs like this

```
<TextInput 
          name='foo'
          keyboardType='numeric'
          maxLength={4}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />

<TextInput 
          name='bar'
          maxLength={4}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
```

Thanks

EDIT:
Here is what I tried for putting id on TextInput

```
<TextInput 
          id='bar'
          name='bar'
          maxLength={4}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />

handleChange(e) {
console.log(e.target.id);
const {name, type, text} = e.nativeEvent;
this.setState({baths: text});
```

}

Comment: Do your `TextInput` have ids?

Comment: My TextInput do not have ids

Comment: How are you using multiple`Textinputs`, can you add the code for that?

Comment: I've added what my TextInputs look like

Answer (score 7):

You cannot *supply* or *mutate* the `props` that have already been defined by the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#props).

Therefore you can create custom component for `TextInput` as

```
const TextInputComponent = ({value, onChangeText, name, ...props}) => (
    <TextInput
        value={value}
        onChangeText={(value) => onChangeText(name, value)} //... Bind the name here
        {...props}
    />
)
```

**Usage** as you would use normally

```
          onChangeValue = (name, value) => {
             console.log(name, value)
             // Set the state according to your needs here
          }

          <TextInputComponent
            value={this.state.value}
            onChangeText={this.onChangeValue}
            name={'Pritish'}
          />
```

Comment: I heard having arrow functions in render could cause performance issues as renders create new objects (I've known developers that have run into this problem in react native). Will using arrow functions in a stateless component like this cause performance issues?

Comment: Since these stateless components do not their own `life cycles`, and will be rendered only on call, it will create the instance just once, and modify it based on the props supplied to it.

Answer (score 7):

Or you can simply do:

```js
<TextInput 
             keyboardType='numeric'
             maxLength={4}
             onChange={e => this.handleChange(e,'foo')}
           />
<TextInput 
             name='bar'
             maxLength={4}
             onChange={e => this.handleChange(e,'bar')}
           />
```

and then in ts file

```
handleChange(event,name){
    // whatever
}
```

Edit: If you are worried about performance, you can use datasets. Any attribute prepended by `data-` are added to `target.dataset` object.

```
<TextInput 
             data-name='foo'
             keyboardType='numeric'
             maxLength={4}
             onChange={this.handleChange}
           />
<TextInput 
             data-name='bar'
             maxLength={4}
             onChange={this.handleChange}
           />
```

and then in ts file

```
handleChange(event){
    const {name} = event.target.dataset
    // whatever
}
```

Comment: Great! I implemented exactly as you said and it worked like a charm!

Comment: but inline function will  cause re-rendering

Comment: is there any other way with using inline function ?

Comment: event.target.dataset is undefined

Comment: Are you sure you correct formats ? I frequently use dataset in code and it works smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

React Native does not have event.target.name

You have to define the name on your own and then pass the name to a function that will handle the TextInput changes.

```
const handleTextChanges = (mytextname) => {
    return (val) => {
        setState({ ...data, [mytextname]: val })
    }
}

<TextInput
    placeholder='text name'
    onChangeText={handleTextChanges('mytextname')}
/>
```

Comment: You should use `onChangeText={() => handleTextChange('mytextname')}`

Answer (score 0):

onChangeText={() => this.handelChange("yourStateName")}

handleChange = (yourStatename) => (inputtext) => {
 setState({ [yourStatename]: inputtext })

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

none of these worked for me. Ppl just putting bs here.

The answer is so simple, not sure why ppl are complicating this.
Just use the following version of onChangeText:

```
onChangeText:(txt)=>{handleSubmit({sender:"name", val:txt})},
```

handle submit is:

```
function handleSubmit({sender, val}){
   console.log("Received following Value "+val +" from " + "sender = "+sender)}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this

```js
const [myForm, setMyForm] = useState({
  name: '',
  phone: ''
})

const handleChange = (text, inputType) => {
  console.log('Text', text, ' InputType', inputType)
  setMyForm(prevForm => ({
   ...prevForm,
   [inputType] : text
  })
}


<View>
  <TextInput
    onChangeText={(text) => handleChange(text, 'phone')}
    style={styles.textInput}
    placeholder="Phone"
  />
  <TextInput
    style={styles.textInput}
    onChangeText={(text) => handleChange(text, 'email')}
    placeholder="Email"
  />
</View>
```