# Some changes in function and setState function?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I am doing such things in reactjs but when I started learning react-native it is not working can you tell me how to perform such tasks??

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View, Form } from 'react-native';
import { FormLabel, FormInput, FormValidationMessage, Button } from 'react-native-elements';

class Header extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email : '',
      password : '',
    };
  }
  inputData = event => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]:event.target.value
    });
  }
  submitData = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <Text style= {{fontSize : 40, marginTop : 50, marginLeft : 100, fontWeight : 'bold'}}>
          New App!
        </Text>
          <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
          <FormInput name='email' type='email' onChange={this.inputData}/>
          <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
          <FormInput name='password' type='password' onChange={this.inputData}/>
          <Button title='Submit' onPress={this.submitData} style={{marginTop:20}}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default Header;
```

As you can see over here is that when I used onChange the values are not getting assigned.

I know how to use with onChangeText and it's working also, but can you tell me why the above approach is not working and if not then any significant reasons???

Comment: So, for React Native there is an `onChangeText` and it is working but `onChange` is not working in your code? Is this the exact problem?

Comment: Yes. @devserkan

Comment: Then try `event.nativeEvent.name` and `event.nativeEvent.value` instead of `event.target.name` and `event.target.value`

Comment: @devserkan Your solution is not working, please can you describe more.

Comment: I don't know React Native, this is why I can't provide a solution directly :) But, I've learned that it is not `event.nativeEvent.value`, it is `event.nativeEvent.text`. But, I can't find a way to grab the name value. So, like me, you can dig the Google a little bit :) I'm trying this on Expo and I can see `event.nativeEvent.text` works.

Comment: Yes, it's something changes but not the way I am expecting.

Comment: There is no name prop either for `TextInput` from `react-native` or `FormInput` from `react-native-elements`. See this workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50019980/7060441 And maybe we can say a duplicate for your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way, use `onChangeText` instead of `onChange`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View, Form } from 'react-native';
import { FormLabel, FormInput, FormValidationMessage, Button } from 'react-native-elements';

class Header extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email : '',
      password : '',
    };
  }
  inputData = event => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]:event.target.value
    });
  }

  inputEmail = text => {
    this.setState({
      email: text
    })
  }
  inputPassword = text => {
    this.setState({
      password: text
    })
  }
  submitData = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <Text style= {{fontSize : 40, marginTop : 50, marginLeft : 100, fontWeight : 'bold'}}>
          New App!
        </Text>
          <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
          <FormInput value={this.state.email} name='email' type='email' onChangeText={this.inputEmail}/>
          <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
          <FormInput value={this.state.password} name='password' type='password' onChangeText={this.inputPassword}/>
          <Button title='Submit' onPress={this.submitData} style={{marginTop:20}}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default Header;
```

Comment: I don't want to create multiple functions. Because I know the above approach is working which you mentioned.

Comment: @yashChoksi what do you mean by multiple functions? This library react-native-elements allows only onChangeText but not onChange so it's library specific. If you want to use onChange then use normal input element or the other library which supports onChange. This answer resolves your OP issue. Please do accept and if you have any other issues post it as a separate question

Comment: yes @Think-Twice, FormInput of react-native-elements just have onChangeText (with argument is text value, doesn't have name). If you want to use 1 function to handle you can try https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-textfield with style similar.